# Updating something on angular with an event from another library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a total noob with angular, but I am trying to understand how to do the following.

I am using keycloak and keycloak.js (https://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.1.0.Final/userguide/html/ch08.html) and they have their custom callbacks, like onAuthSuccess.  If I want to update something like the login name how should call this onAuthSuccess.  Should I create a function outside of angular, and call the scope, which seems messy.  Or is there a way to call this function in angular, like in provider or a factory, but I have no clue how to do this.

Update ********

In normal javascript you would have something like this

```
var keycloak = new Keycloak("path/to/keycloak.json");
keycloak.onAuthSuccess(){
//code to do on auth success
}
```

And in order to update something in my scope I would have to do something like

```
var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
```

but it seems messy.

Is there a way to do this in my project.

Comment: I'm sure that chapter 8 is fascinating reading, but could you provide some short relevant code instead?

Comment: You dont need to read chapter 8, it was just a reference, but if you need code, here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely going to want to make a call to `$apply()`

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   [exception handling](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), [executing watches](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

I am unfarmiliar with this library, but from what you shared, an example would likely include...

```
var keycloak = new Keycloak("path/to/keycloak.json");
keycloak.onAuthSuccess(){
    // do stuff - likely modify $scope
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Check out the [AngularJS $apply() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) and some more [explanation on the project wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) for some more insight on the why.

Comment: but you have to obtain the scope some how, otherwise you get that $scope.apply() is not a method from undefinded or something like that

Comment: Isnt this `onAuthSuccess` callback defined in your controller where `$scope` resides? If not, where are you defining that? @JuanDiego

Comment: It was outside, but I wasnt thinking about declaring the function inside the controller, thanks

Comment: Give it a shot and let me know if it fires like you'd expect? @JuanDiego

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is to let the AngularJs code handle events in response to the other code.  This seemed like the lesser of various evils, because it let me write the angular code where I wanted, in the controller.  Its not ideal though, because it introduces an external dependency into the angular controller.

Extending your example:

```
keycloak.onAuthSuccess(){
  //raise some sort of event that angular controller can listen for
}
```

Some potential types of event:

1. DOM event, e.g. `$('#outer').trigger('authSuccess.tellAngular', args);`
2. AngularJs broadcast, e.g. `angular.element($("#outer")).scope().broadcast('authSuccess', args);`

I hope that helps!